# How to set the scalemode of a scene when I transit into it?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, skscene

My problem is when I am trying to switch to a scene, the view of it is different when it was my start scene.

The problem is -I think- the scale mode, so I tried to set the scale mode but it didn't work. This what I have tried:

```
let skView = self.view! as SKView

let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
gameScene.size = skView.bounds.size
gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill

skView.presentScene(gameScene , transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
```

And this:

```
let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)

gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill

self.view?.scene!.presentScene(gameScene , transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
```

And I have tried to set the scale mode of the scene in the `didMoveToView()` function.

None of these methods helps, any help?

Comment: The code above is in your GameViewController?

Comment: no in the start scene in a node button

Comment: the scale mode in the controller is Resizefill

Comment: How do you initialize the first scene in your GameViewController? After initializing correctly, you don't need to change the scene size anymore.

Comment: currently i have two scenes in my game "GameMenu" and "GameScene" i want to put gamemenu scene as my first scene and this is how i intialize it in the gamecontroller

Comment: i will post it in answer

Comment: Do you load from .sks file or just add everything programmatically?

Comment: I will show you an example, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to transition from one scene to another. Supposed `GameMenu` is your first scene and you want to transition to `GameScene`.

In **GameViewController** initialize `GameMenu` size:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameMenu(size: view.bounds.size)
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Now, you should be at the first scene. When to transition to `GameScene`, add the following code as needed:

```
let nextScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
```

And now everything's done and `GameScene` appears. Check this [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jix30rajl1kptz/Transition.zip?dl=0) if you have any problem.

Comment: did you miss "if" before "let" in this line 'let scene = GameMenu(size: view.bounds.size)' or you meant to make it like this ?

Comment: @AdeebAbaza just remove if statement

Comment: #1 Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: #2 Extra argument 'size' in call

Comment: @AdeebAbaza Errors occurs in which file? Did my code conflict with your code somewhere? Try to fix it yourself and at least you can run the sample project I attached and compare with your code.

Comment: no errors but nothing happens it still the same problem

Comment: @AdeebAbaza Have you downloaded the project at last of my post? If problem still exists in that project, describe the problem in details.

Comment: Okay i will see what happen

Comment: ok i downloaded it, it works fine, i will tell you the difference between the scene if it is my start scene and if its next scene , and by the way i want the scale mode is resizefill and this how i put it in the gamecontroller and in this scale mode how the scene i want to so , the objects in the next scene smaller than the actual scene if it was my start scene

Comment: sorry there was a different problem i solve it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameMenu(fileNamed:"GameMenu") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
                        skView.showsFPS = true
                        skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```